# devise sign_in is not working properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I want to create the function of user authentication for my web site(with rails), so adopt gem 'devise'. But I faced a trouble when setting devise.

I tried these commands.

1. `rails g devise:install`
2. `rails g devise User`

and migrate my database, setting route.

According to some articles on the Internet, these only 2 commands give me the function of authentication.

Ofcourse, I implemented sign_up and sign_out.
But, something is wrong when I go to sign_in page.
I write the situation below.

1. go to users/sign_in
2. type email and password (that is information of registered user in database)
3. Push the 'Login' Button(POST method)
4. render users/sign_in again (??) (the Problem of this question)
5. 1. (when I reload the sign_in page) redirect to root page
   2. (when I push 'LOGIN' Button again) error:'update' method is not found

In '4', I expect redirecting to root page.

Please, tell me how to fix it.

I tried it many times though I deleted or commented out a file or code that might interfere, but I can not do it.

LOG is here:

```
web_1  | 07:43:23 app.1       | Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 172.18.0.1 at 2018-02-01 07:43:23 +0000
web_1  | 07:43:23 app.1       | Cannot render console from 172.18.0.1! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
web_1  | 07:43:23 app.1       | Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
web_1  | 07:43:23 app.1       |   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"EUXiO3ma/Bv10PgTUuzdkokJtHJAbcgAOOhjBGAOyTJXx4cExBzqiKpg8imib7M9PU/wNXvyIgQwJOqjGEFYxA==", "user"=>{"email"=>"user1@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Log in"}
web_1  | 07:43:23 app.1       |   User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["email", "user1@gmail.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
web_1  | 07:43:24 app.1       |    (0.3ms)  BEGIN
web_1  | 07:43:24 app.1       |    (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
web_1  | 07:43:24 app.1       |   Rendering vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/devise-4.4.0/app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application
web_1  | 07:43:24 app.1       |   Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/devise-4.4.0/app/views/devise/shared/_links.html.erb (0.7ms)
web_1  | 07:43:24 app.1       |   Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/devise-4.4.0/app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (3.5ms)
web_1  | 07:43:24 app.1       |   Rendered layouts/_header.html.slim (3.2ms)
web_1  | 07:43:24 app.1       | Completed 200 OK in 156ms (Views: 26.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)
```

Comment: I suppose ROLLBACK is suspicious, and use pry-byebug to search.

I think this rollback comes from `warden.authenticate!`

source is here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb#L19

Comment: Are you sure the user model has been created correctly? You could try pulling up the model if it's there (in the console) and running `user.errors.messages`.

Comment: @jon1467 thanks your comment. When I checked on rails console, the user was certainly created. But before starting procedure of 'create method', I stop the execution and run `current_user.errors.messages`, I got `{:password=>["can't be blank"]}`.

Comment: Aha! That's a good clue. Seems like your form may not be setup correctly then, or you may have settings stopping the password from being changed if it's not complex enough.

Comment: OK. I realized the problem. In User Model, I set `validates :password, presence: true`. Maybe, that was bad validation for database created by devise. So easy problem.. I'm sorry and appreciate your support!! Thanx a lot.

Comment: Ah, well done for finding it. I think I can explain why that would be a problem. Devise user models don't actually have password fields, only fields for encrypted passwords. When you set a password with `user.password=`, it is actually updating the encrypted password field. So when your code wants to check for the field, it's correct when it complains as the password field genuinely isn't present. Glad you got it sorted!

Comment: @jon1467 Thank you for last comment. I gained a better understanding of devise gem.  Thank you for polite and wonderful correspondence!!!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)